# Google Analytics Ecommerce Overview - Revenue Data not showing

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Does anyone know why the Revenue Data does not show on the overview?

This is the code snippet on the e-commerce page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAjoq.png

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-******-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

Sales Performance also shows no data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebPmK.png

Is there something anyone can suggest here? Also if you need more info to answer the question can you let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the transaction data to Google Analytics, for both the transaction and any product that is included in the transaction. A pageview will not by itself include the necessary information.

Example [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce)

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'Acme Clothing',  // affiliation or store name
    '11.99',          // total - required
    '1.29',           // tax
    '5',              // shipping
    'San Jose',       // city
    'California',     // state or province
    'USA'             // country
  ]);

   // add item might be called for every item in the shopping cart
   // where your ecommerce engine loops through each item in the cart and
   // prints out _addItem for each
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
    'T-Shirt',        // product name
    'Green Medium',   // category or variation
    '11.99',          // unit price - required
    '1'               // quantity - required
  ]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

The transaction ID is the key that ties individual products to the transaction. The necessary code must be generated by your website, GA cannot do this by itself.

And you should really switch to the current version of the tracking code.